# What is a non-versioned file?

Tags: php, linux, redcap

I've got a php program, on my debian server.
If set it up and changed the php version to 8.1.
Now the server is giving me an error message:

> Some non-versioned files are outdated - WARNING: One or more files that are not included in REDCap's version directory but reside in your web server's main REDCap directory were found outdated, and thus need to be replaced. Click the download button below to download a zip file that contains the files you need to replace.

I want to know what a non-versioned file is, so I can fix that problem.

After downloading that .zip file I took a look inside and I realized it was empty...
I didnt change anything in the Servers main directory...

Thank you

Comment: A file that's not managed by version control.

Comment: It's unclear where/when/how you're seeing this error. "The server is giving me an error" is a pretty vague description of what context it's happening in.

Comment: Total shot in the dark, but check for line-ending differences (CRLF Vs. LF) between your local file(s) and the remote file(s). Some version control systems will detect them as different (as they should). If not, you need to get more information about the differences, or possibly, you can ignore this error. It all depends on the context which we don't have.

Comment: You should take this to the REDCap community. If you are installing REDCap then you ought to have a login to the community. Non-versioned in this case refers to files that are in the base redcap application directory on your server, in which you would also have 'versioned' directories for the different versions of the applications you have installed, i.e. `redcap_v12.5.10/`, `redcap_v12.5.16/`, etc.

Comment: Ahh alright, i was able to fix it. Thank you all!

Comment: @Jangari, consider putting your comment in an answer.   (@Barmar, among the lingo used by REDCap admins, we use the definition described by @Jangair.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In REDCap server administration, application files can be either versioned or non-versioned. Versioned files are those files that exist within a directory named for the version, i.e. `redcap_v13.1.0`. Non-versioned files are those that are outside this versioned file structure, in REDCap's base directory.

Below is a sample directory structure (altered so this answer does not expose the file structure of a non-open application):

```
.

└──redcap
   ├── init.php
   ├── index.php
   ├── redcap_v13.1.0
   │   ├── tests.ini
   │   ├── unit.php
   │   └── api.bat
   ├── tmp
   │   └── index.php
   └── debug.php
```

Files `tests.ini`, `unit.php` and `api.bat` are versioned, and everything else is non-versioned.

Upgrades to the REDCap application mostly affect versioned files, but occasionally an upgrade will modify non-versioned files, which the application itself is incapable of directly modifying on the server. In these cases the application directs the administrator to download a zip file containing the modified non-versioned files and instructions on installing them.

If this zip file was empty for you, then that might indicate an incomplete upgrade. Some admins in the community have recently advocated for publishing hashes alongside releases to allow admins to ensure that the release has been correctly downloaded.

If this issue persists (though your comment suggests not), then I'd recommend taking this issue to the REDCap Admin Community, which you ought to have access to if you can access the code.